# How do I convert a horizontal, panoramic skymap texture into a "dome" version of itself?

Tags: textures, uv-mapping, skybox

How do I convert the following skymap image:

[image: Panoramic Version]

into a "dome" version like the one below?

[image: Dome Version]

I'm looking towards making use of Adobe Photoshop for the task at hand. However, I'm at a loss on what tools I'm going to use and how I will go about it.

So, **how do I convert a horizontal, panoramic skymap texture into a "dome" version of itself?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple method using only Photoshop:

1. Crop the image vertically to remove anything that should be below the horizon (ie. not part of the sky dome)
2. Scale up the height of the image to make it square
3. Filter -> Distort -> Polar Coordinates

Comment: 4. select circle to select the circular region /
5. select inverse /
6. fill with black /
result: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75238938/dome.jpg

Comment: Actually, leaving the colours at the outside as-is can make the texture more resistant to bleeding at the horizon in the event of downscaling. The coloured texels don't do any harm there, or even increase the memory footprint under typical block compression schemes used on GPUs.